# Why does my "for" loop run only two times?

Tags: c, for-loop, while-loop, breakpoints

The task I was doing is to enter 5 random numbers that are with 5 digits, To compress them and get their sum. So how do we compress them? We get rid of the second and fourth digit. For example 12345 to 10305.

This was my code .

```
int main()
{
    int n=5,i,j,number5,num1,num3,numb5,sum;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) // 5 times we read next for loop right ?
        for(j=0;j<i;j++){ // this loop read 5 times 5 digits number 
            scanf("%d",&number5); // scanf 1 number
            while(number5){ // while number isn't 0 ( false )
                num1=number5/10000;
                num1*=10000;
                num3=(number5%10000)%1000/100;
                num3*=100;
                numb5=(number5%10000)%1000%100%10; 
                numb5*=1;// mathematic operations to get to 1st third and 5th number
                number5=0; // set the number5 to 0 so we can go out of while right ?
            }
            sum=num1+num3+numb5; // we get the sum of the first 5 digits and we get it on the second when j++ right ?

        }
         printf("%d",sum);// on the end of all five number with 5 digits we get the sum right ?
}
```

So why does my `for` loop run only two times instead of five?

Comment: Compress? What doe it mean?

Comment: @EugeneSh. OP means to remove digits. "Compress" isn't really the right word here.

Comment: Why is `j<i` the condition in the second `for` loop?

Comment: The statement `numb5=(number5%10000)%1000%100%10; ` is mathematically identical to `numb5=number5 % 10;`.

Comment: If you want to input 5 numbers then all you need is a loop that runs for 5 iterations. There's no need for 3 nested loops.

Comment: @3Dave you are right huh , and sorry for my bad English . And that j<i is to connect the first loop ? so i can read 5 times by 5 times 5 digit numbers ?

Comment: @interjay i need to input 5 times 5 numbers that are 5 digits .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just make `j<i` in the second loop to `j<5` and you can get sum of five 5-digit compressed numbers for `n` times.

Comment: This work but why my dont ? when i want to scale with the int i ?

Comment: Ok i understand my mistake my is is 0 so we go in and the 0<0 then back up at the i and go on i++ then run 0<1 and j++ come 1<1 and again we make the same mistake right ?

Answer (score 0):

You're really over-thinking this.

```
int n;

for(int i=0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    // read first number eg 12345
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int d1 = n % 10;    // ones place = 5
    n /= 100;           // n becomes 123
    int d100 = n % 10;  // hundreds place = 3
    n /= 100;           // n becomes 1
    int d10000 = n % 10;    // ten thousands place = 1

    int smallSum = 100*d10000 + 10*d100 + d1;
    // prints 135 
    printf("sum version 1 = %d\n", smallSum); 

    int bigSum = 10000*d10000 + 100*d100 + d1;
    // prints 10305
    printf("sum version 2 = %d\n",bigSum);     
}
```

[See it in action here](https://onlinegdb.com/r1J-K5rhB).

Comment: not really , man i need to insert 5 times 5 different numbers that are 5 digits and just  what i sad 'compress' just to get the first third and fifth number by their own positions like tenths of a hundred and thousands , and then calculate the sum .

Comment: @Starterpack That is exactly what this does.

Comment: Look , not the sum of 1+3+5 but 1000+300+5 do you understand now how ?

Comment: @Starterpack I misunderstood. Corrected above.

Comment: @Starterpack Your post says that `12345` should produce `135`, not `10305` as your comment suggests. Which is it?

Comment: 10305 but ok maybe its my bad i have a really bad English .. Sorry dear .

Comment: @Starterpack I updated to do it both ways. Don't worry about the English - I speak exactly one language fluently.

Answer (score 0):

The errors i mentioned in the snippet were the only issue rest everything was fine.
Please refer attached snippet.

```
// only two loops are required    
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    scanf("%d",&number5);
    sum=0;
    while(number5){ 
            num1=number5/10000;
            num1*=100;//it should be 100 isntead of 10000
            num3=(number5%10000)%1000/100;
            num3*=10;// it should be 10 istead of 100
            numb5=(number5%10000)%1000%100%10; 
            numb5*=1;
            number5=0; 
        }
    sum=num1+num3+numb5; 
    printf("%d\n",sum);
}
```

Comment: Its ok i already fix it but ty for the help i appreciate that .

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main()
{
    int n=5,i,j,number5,num1,num3,numb5;
    int sum=0;


    for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
       scanf("%d",&number5);//runs 5 times to get 5 inputs

       sum+=(number5/10000)*10000; // take the value of first position
       sum+=((number5/100)%10)*100; // take the value of third position
       sum+=(number5%10);// take the value of fifth position

        }
         printf("%d",sum);
}
```